# How to exclude x value with a x length

Tags: sql-server

This is my table:

```
Employee_num    Name       surname
-----------------------------------------
355788          john        dow
3556698         chris       staple
9888766         max         smith
5666            jean        baker
```

How do I exclude employee numbers that starts with 3 and has a length of 6 characters?

SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE NOT 
(
   LEFT(Employee_num, 1) = '3'
   AND 
   LEN(Employee_num) = 6
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  [ID],[Value] FROM [TestTable] where left([value],1) <>3 and LEN([Value])<>6
```